# Payment methods are not showing up on multi shipping

Tags: magento2

Payment options are showing fine:

```
/default/checkout/#payment
```

Payment options are **not** showing up:

```
/default/multishipping/checkout/billing/
```

Upon clicking: 'Go to Review Your Order' - the following message is displayed:

> We can't complete your order because you don't have a payment method
>   set up.

The console does not show any errors.

This happens in magento community: 2.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento Multishipping doesn't support built-in Magento online payment methods.

To make custom payment integration available for Multishipping you need to add

```
<payment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Payment:etc/payment.xsd">
<methods>
    <method name="payment_code">
        <allow_multiple_address>1</allow_multiple_address>
    </method>
</methods>
```

to `payment.xml` file in your payment module. Also, `payment_code` should be the payment method code for your integration.
To make integration usable, you might need to add custom js components for payment form.

If you want to add Braintree, PayPal, Authorize.net or other built-in integrations to Multishipping, they won't work without customizations. It's not enough to add them to `payment.xml`.

Starting from Magento 2.2.4 release, Cybersource payment integration will be available for Multishipping.
Also, we improved Multishipping components to simplify integration with online payment solutions.